# table is empty or not

Tags: java

```
Statement st=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
Connection con=null;

String sql="select * from employee;";

try{

                con= new Database().getMySqlConnection();
                st=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

    while(rs.next())
    {
if(rs.getInt("id")!=-1)     
{
  %>
 <tr><td align="center"><%=rs.getInt("id")%></td> 
 <td align="center"><%=rs.getString("name")%></td>
  <td align="center"><%=rs.getInt("salary")%> </td>
   <td align="center"><%=rs.getString("Designation") %></td>
}
    else
    {

        out.println("table is empty");
    } 
    }   
  }


                catch (SQLException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
```

In this program I want to show data in table on page, by retrieving from table if not empty, if table is empty then show message or print that table is empty. But it can't display any message, when there is data in table it works correctly.
But when table is empty the error message is not displayed.

I saw many examples on the net, perform wasNull() method , islast(), iffirst() method etc, but still problem persists.

Plz suggest the solution. This program is in java.

Comment: i already use count method on select ,,,but not working.......

Comment: -1 - Please do us the courtesy of formatting your code and writing your questions properly.   Did they teach you about punctuation in school?  Did they teach you about indentation in your programming classes? This example is truly horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your empty table statement should be outside the while statement. Use a flag.

```
while(rs.next())
{
    flag = 1;
    if(rs.getInt("id")!=-1)     
       {
        <tr><td align="center"><%=rs.getInt("id")%></td> 
        <td align="center"><%=rs.getString("name")%></td>
        <td align="center"><%=rs.getInt("salary")%> </td>
        <td align="center"><%=rs.getString("Designation") %></td>
       }
}   
if ( flag == 0 )
     out.println("Table is empty");
```

the `next()` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) keeps moving the cursor forward one row at a time. If you enter the while loop,it means there is something in the table.

Comment: sir  i dont have 15 reputation

Comment: You can still accept the answer,look for the tick below the voting arrows next to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your message is in while loop. If there is no data in table than rs.next will return false.
You have to move msg outside the loop.

ither you can use boolean var whose value changes in while to find if any data was returned or you can use combination of if-else & do-while.

```
 if(rs.next()){
     do{
        //process data
       }while(rs/next);
 }else{
     //Print MSG
 }
```

Comment: sir what is the diffrence between if(rs.next) and while(rs.next).....i think   if checks for boolean and while run until nextnot found in table...is it???????

Comment: None. Except that while is used for looping n times while if provide the option to execute block of code based on certain condition is true or false. while(rs.next)- Code within while will not be executed. In case of if, the else block will be executed if rs.next returns false.